# Firebase Authentication: [firebase_auth/no-such-provider] User not linked to account with given provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm encountering an issue with Firebase Authentication in my Flutter app. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: [firebase_auth/no-such-provider] User was not linked to an account with the given provider.
at FirebaseAuthUserHostApi.getIdToken(messages.pigeon.dart:1594)
at MethodChannelUser.getIdToken(method_channel_user.dart:43)
at jwtTokenStream.<fn>(auth_util.dart:30)
```

I attempted to implement Firebase Authentication in my Flutter app following the official documentation. I set up the necessary dependencies, initialized Firebase in my app, and configured authentication providers. Additionally, I checked for any misconfigurations in my Firebase project settings.

I expected that users, once authenticated, would be linked to their accounts with the specified providers. When attempting to retrieve the ID token using the relevant method, I anticipated a successful retrieval without encountering any errors related to provider linkage.

The app is throwing the following error: Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: [firebase_auth/no-such-provider] User was not linked to an account with the given provider. This occurs when trying to obtain the ID token, suggesting an issue with the provider linkage. I've reviewed the code and Firebase settings but haven't identified the cause of the error.

Code:

```
String? _currentJwtToken;
final jwtTokenStream = FirebaseAuth.instance
    .idTokenChanges()
    .map((user) async => _currentJwtToken = await user?.getIdToken())
    .asBroadcastStream();
```

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show us how you authenticate in Firebase?

Comment: can you check if internet connection is ok? I get this when disconnected